# Slow performance leafletjs in WebView on Android

Tags: android, webview, leaflet, gis, polygon

I'm using leafletjs in an Android Application to render local polygons (without CRS Information) in geojson format, without maptiles. Unfortunately, zooming and other touch movement are very laggy. My geojson file contains 3000 polygons. Is there any solution to this problem, the only thing I can find is a solution for markers.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Here is my code:

In onCreate:

```
public void loadMap(){

        scanFiles();
        checkStoragePermissions();

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        WebSettings webSettings =
                webview.getSettings();

        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG);

        webview.setWebChromeClient(
                new WebChromeClient());

        File leafletMap = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/LeafletMap/Map.html");

        webview.loadUrl("file:///" + leafletMap.getAbsolutePath());

    }
```

And my HTML-File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Leaflet Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/leaflet/leaflet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>

    <style>
    body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html, body, #mapid {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100vw;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="mapid"></div>
    <script>
        var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
            crs: L.CRS.Simple
        });

        //Add local
        var layer;
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'file:///android_asset/poly.json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status !== 200) return
            var blahlayer = L.geoJSON(xhr.response).getBounds();

            mymap.fitBounds(blahlayer);

            L.geoJSON(xhr.response).addTo(mymap);
        };
        xhr.send();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try VectorGrid.Slicer from https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/ if you haven't yet. It'll help simplifying and lazy-loading geometries.

Comment: As an intermediate solution, you can also try first to use canvas renderer instead of svg, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031136/leaflet-polyline-disappears-on-pan/42031822?r=SearchResults#42031822

Comment: It's a little smoother with canvas renderer but it's still a bit notchy. I'm trying the Slicer but my Polygons don't show up. This is how I do is: L.vectorGrid.slicer(geoJ).addTo(mymap);